# android java transformerexception filenotfoundexception

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to save an xml file to the Android assets folder, with the following code:

```
try {
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("http://www.website.com"));
    transformer.transform(source, result);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now the website generates an xml file, which I want to update. When running this code I get a TransformerAxception: FileNotFoundException.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot save a file to assetFolder. An apk is  a zipped file and all folders inside Your project cannot be touched.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What about an URL of a website? I have a webpage which generates an xml file where I have to change some data. How can I do that instead?

Comment: You mean change the xml file on the website? Or change the loaded xml file and save it for example on the sd card?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
   file:///android_asset/file.xml
```

Try this

```
    getAssets().open("file.xml")
```

Comment: please read exactly...you cannot save to the asset folder because an apk is a zipped file. JeroenD want to save not to read.

Comment: Thanks, but I changed the question since the xml file is generated by a webpage, and I don't just have the file in the assets folder anymore.